JSON Extracted values not getting updated with iteration
Thread group has 4 requests, first being the Login request.The test plan is executed in a way that login request executes only once and other 3 request are iterated multiple times. A value "OrderID" is been captured from 2nd request using JSON extractor and passed in the 3rd request body.
The issue is, when the script is executed for certain duration/iterations, the value OrderID is been extracted every time correctly from 2nd request.But it passes only the value captured during 1st iteration in the 3rd request body throughout the test.
Lets say, if the test is executed for 3 iterations,below are the captured OrderIDs,

1st iteration OrderID = abcd1234
2nd iteration OrderID = efgh5678
3rd iteration OrderID = xyz7890

So instead of passing efgh5678 in 2nd iteration and xyz7890 in 3rd iteration, every time abcd1234 value is passed in the 3rd request body.
How to fix this issue and send right value every time.

If it's "correctly extracted" you should see the updated values each time.

Make sure that JSON Extractor is placed correctly, like as a child of the 2nd request, see JMeter Scoping Rules for more details

Temporarily enable storing JMeter response data for 2nd request to see whether you're creating the new order using View Results Tree listener. You can also double check what is the match for the JSON Extractor using JSON Path Tester mode:


Re-visit your JSONPath Expression, it might be the case it extracts the first match only and you might need to use i.e. a Filter Operator or something like this


In general we cannot provide a comprehensive answer without seeing response data and how your test plan is built, going forward consider supplying a sufficient amount of details or minimal reproducible example
